RTL_433 ASK Manchester?
I am currently working with an Arduino R3 and an Amplitude Shift Keying(ASK) 4800 bps receiver I found online. For the device I'm working to collect data from, it is a pressure sensor that uses ASK Manchester (IEEE 802.3) Encoding at 434MHz w/ 4000 bps. I have done some digging and found an "ASK" implementation and "FSK Manchester" in the library, but nothing specific to "ASK Manchester" encoding. For those experienced with the library, does the encoding need to be accounted for in software? At this stage of implementation, I am looking to receive a raw bit stream from the sensor to confirm setup.
I started out with the Arduino extension of the RTL_433 library, specifically the RH_ASK library. I have a tool for the sensor that gets the device ID and other information, so i know that the sensor side is working. I have an oscilloscope connected to the digital out of the rf receiver, i have confirmed that the signal is being picked up by the Rx, a concern I have with it is that it may not be hitting proper logic levels (scope shots below). I am also unaware of how the recv and available functions work for the RF library. I have confirmed that the digital pin on the arduino is seeing the logic transistions.
Update: looking to implement this library
wave processed through ASK Recv, seen through digital out pin
sets of information being sent, can see data within each pulse
a single pulse with data enclosed
a single bit from transmission, 250 uS time for one bit, split into 125 uS on/off sections for Manchester encoding
another data packet from same transmission, this one has iffy logic levels
scope shot of potentially unreadable bits or noise

It doesn't look much like Manchester encoding to me. There should be a clear carrier wave on one phase with 0 and 1 encoded by the direction of the intervening transition.

Not quite sure what you exactly are asking. If you are asking "Is there a file in the Radiohead that already solves this implementation"? From the product link that you provided, I can see that sparkfun recommend using RadioHead, from there I can find the documentation of RadioHead RH_ASK class.

@hcheung updated question for you

Okay, ASK is an RF modulation scheme, it doesn't care how the bits are encoded, it simply takes the incoming data and modulate the RF carrier based on ASK. How to encode/decode your data based on Manchester encoding before send over with ASK, there is a library that can be used for Machester encoding or decoding, or you could do with a clock running at twice of the baud rate you wish to achieve with some bit banging, see Machester code for the basic concept.
